# What is the explicit version of the Peter Weyl Theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

While the name "Peter-Weyl" is reserved for the compact group case, I prefer to talk in greater generality. Let $G$ be a unimodular type I topological group with a fixed Haar measure. The theorem that I am interested is the one that says that in this case there exists a unique measure on the set of irreducible unitary representations $\hat{G}$, called the Plancherel measure, which gives an isomorphism:
$$L^2(G)\cong \int_{\pi\in\hat{G}}^{\oplus} End(\pi)^*$$

(This is often phrased with $\pi\otimes \pi^*$ rather than $End(\pi)^*$, but for the sake of making this isomorphism explicit, I think it would be best to use $End(\pi)^*$, namely the space of matrix coefficients, instead. They are of course isomorphic to one another.)

My question is: what is this map explicitly? What is its inverse?

Taking some inspiration from the abelian compact situation, my best guess is the following:

Starting with the matrix coefficients $(h_{\pi})_{\pi\in\hat{G}}$, the function on $G$ would take an element $g\in G$ to $\int_{\pi\in\hat{G}} h_{\pi}(\pi(g))$.

Going in the reverse direction, my guess is as follows: starting with an $f\in L^2(G)$, at every $\pi \in \hat{G}$ the coordinate at $\pi\in\hat{G}$ would be the matrix coefficient taking $\varphi\in End(\pi)$ to $\int_G f(g)\varphi(\pi(g))$. Or perhaps it should be $\int_G \overline{f(g)}\varphi(\pi(g))$? $\int_G f(g)\overline{\varphi(\pi(g))}$, which seems closest to the term in Pontryagin duality, can't be right, because that wouldn't be a functional on $End(\pi)$ (i.e., $\int_G f(g)\overline{c\varphi(\pi(g))}\neq c\int_G f(g)\overline{\varphi(\pi(g))}$)...

Am I on the right track here? Can you help me out with the details?

Comment: Well your initial formula is incorrect, and that's why it might be a good idea to reserve the name "Peter-Weyl theorem" for the actual Peter-Weyl theorem :)

Comment: The point is that you do not get ${\rm End}(\pi)^*$ if $\pi$ is infinite-dimensional, which it often/usually is for the level of generality stated in your question. Actual functional analysis is needed here for correct statements

Comment: What you are after, more or less, is the inverse Fourier transform for "suitable" (=2nd countable Type I unimodular) **locally compact** groups. If you're able to get a hold of Folland's book on Harmonic Analysis then things are explained there in some detail

Comment: BTW the magic words are not "Peter-Weyl" which is really a theorem about compact groups. (Even for $G={\bf R}$ the matrix coefficients of the irreps do not belong to $C_0(G)$ and do not span a dense subspace of $C_b(G)$, so I don't think you can call the isomorphism you're aiming for a "Peter-Weyl theorem" for ${\bf R}$.) Instead, the magic words are "Plancherel theorem" or "Plancherel formula"

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I am happy to understand the compact situation first, in which case there are no infinite dimensional irreducible reps. In that case, what would be the correct variant among those in my question?

Comment: Okay, I've read the relevant part of Folland. Folland uses $End(\pi)$ rather than the matrix coefficients, so it's not exactly the same language. If I understand correctly, the correct translation to the language above is the following: instead of $(h_{\pi})_{\pi\in\hat{G}}$ going to the function taking an element $g\in G$ to $\int_G h_{\pi}(\pi(g))$, it should be $\int_G dim(\pi) h_{\pi}(\pi(g))$; and instead of $f\in L^2(G)$ going to $(\varphi \mapsto \int_G f(g)\varphi(\pi(g)))_{\pi}$ it should go to $(\varphi\mapsto \int_G f(g)\varphi(\pi(g^{-1})))_{\pi}$. Right?